# Use C structs only and stay OOPy?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, struct, pointer-to-member

Say you have:

```
struct c_struct {
   int value;
   /* other stuff */
   void (* dump)();
};
```

and you'd like to, at some point:

```
c_struct_obj->dump();
```

I assume there's no way you could instantiate a c_struct object such that its particular "dump" function knows its particular "value" the way C++ methods know member variables (via the implicit "this" I suppose)? I guess I know the answer already ("no"). If so, are there other ways of using C structs in an OOPy way?

Comment: Choose your language - in C++ you can do as you want, and in C you can't.  Since the question is tagged with both, it is not possible to answer it well.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "Say you want to stick to C compilers, and you have..." at the beginning. I tagged C++ since I wanted to apply C++ ideas to vanilla C, but that is a little misleading. Woops.

Comment: Can you clarify the scenario that triggers this question, or is this hypothetical?

Comment: I actually did want to dump a struct when debugging-- which got me thinking. But for this particular need, I suppose I could just inspect the struct in a debugger. I do write code that needs to run as fast as possible so it would be nice to stick to C; I feel more at home in it.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you just have to pass `this` by yourself:

```
struct c_struct {
    int value;
    /* other stuff */
    void (* dump)(struct c_struct *this);
};
```

And then call it with:

```
c_struct_obj->dump(c_struct_obj);
```

Comment: I feared it. I guess a global dump(c_struct_obj) is less typing.

Comment: @carson921, but then you lose the ability to have different `dump()` functions for each 'class' - polymorphism, so to speak.

Comment: @Carl Norum oh, right. I'd need dump_cstruct() and dump_anotherstruct() etc. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @carson921, you can't - but when creating your objects, you can assign appropriate functions to each.  Then the callers don't need to know what the type is, as long as they have `dump` at the same offset in the structure.

Comment: @Carl Norum thanks. I just wrote a dump function that is static and specific to a compilation unit (file), so the caller has to access the dump function via the object, which is a little nicer. I don't think I've thought as far ahead (polymorphism etc) as you have on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use structs in this way but its a pain.  All c++ member function get a *this pointer passed to them you can do the same but your dump functions will need to take the structure that its contained in as a parameter.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a C++ compiler, the only difference between a struct and a class is the default visibility of member variables (classes being private, structs being public). The this pointer is available within member functions.

```
struct test
{
    int x;

    void inc();
};

void test::inc()
{
    x++;
}

int main(void)
{
    test a;
    a.x = 1;
    a.inc();
    int b = a.x;

    return 0;
}
```

b == 2 here.

Comment: But he isn't, else he would just use a C++ member function. Which he isn't - he's using a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and can even do inheritance. But the interfacing with it is a total mess and you get nowhere near, for example, the resource safety involved with C++'s deterministic automatic cleanup. Ultimately, you CAN do OOP in C, but it's just not worth the hassle compared to just using C++, as well as all the other features that C++ offers.

Comment: Thanks. I guess sometimes I just want some more OOP in C but if I go C++ I feel guilty not completely rethinking everything.

Comment: @carson921: Your program in C is probably still incredibly unsafe, regardless of the fact that you now get to notice it because you wrote some safe code.